# Why didn't Nan come back?

Tags: horror, american-horror-story

In American Horror Story 3rd Season "Coven", every major character who died before the last episode either came back to life or came back to continue to participate in the events of the series -- with the exception of Nan. Did the writers reveal a reason for this exception? Or was there a reason given in the show that I didn't catch?

Comment: The actress portrayed a different role

Comment: @Richard I don't know what you mean? I am speaking about only the 3rd season.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Nan's death and why she wasn't brought back to life, I believe that she decided to move on to the other side. After all, Luke (is that his name? I forgot) had been murdered by his mom, leaving Nan all alone. Although she was part of the coven, she was the odd one out, more so than Queenie, in my opinion. A lot of people looked down on her even though she could have probably been up to par with the other witches in terms of conquering the Seven Wonders had she not been killed by Fiona and Marie Laveau. Nan had never really been in a safe haven within her own coven, and just when she though she had found one in Luke, he was killed off.

Nan had enough, so maybe that's why she allowed Papa Legba to guide her to the other side after the deity rejected Nan's soul as sacrifice.

I hope that my answer isn't off and that it helps answer your question.